# how to add an integer value associated with an array?

Tags: java

ok my getBreadInfo code is

```
public static String[] getBreadInfo()  
{   
    ArrayList<String> breadsList = new ArrayList<>();

        try (BufferedReader in =
                new BufferedReader(
                new FileReader("bread.txt")))
        {
            String line = in.readLine();
            while (line != null)
            {
                String[] elems = line.split("~");
                breadsList.add(elems[0]+ " $" + elems[1]);
                line = in.readLine();
            }

        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            return null;
        }
    String[] breadInfo = breadsList.toArray(new String[]{});
    return breadInfo;
}
```

and in my main app to display this array is as

```
public static void displayBreadMenu()  
{  
    System.out.println("=== Select Sandwich Bread ===");

   String[] breadInfo = SandwichDB.getBreadInfo();
   for (String breads : breadInfo)
   {
       System.out.println(breads);
   }
}
```

it prints on console as

=== Select Sandwich Bread ===
White bread  1.50
Wheat bread  1.80
French bread  2.00
Organic bread 2.30

How would I add an integer value to associate with each array? like
1 White bread
2 Wheat bread
3 French bread
4 Organic bread

i'm told my getBread() is similar to getBreadInfo, except it only contains the
bread name, and return another array bread[] for SandwichApp to figure
out which bread the user selected because user type in a number
associate with the bread (index+1), rather than bread name.

Do i write the integer value in my getbread() or is the getBread just to check which bread the user selected?

Comment: thanks both examples were helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about having an counter and appending it while adding to the list.

```
int count=1;
 while (line != null)
            {
                String[] elems = line.split("~");
                breadsList.add(count+" " +elems[0]+ " $" + elems[1]);
                line = in.readLine();
                 count++;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want. Just use a variable to keep count as you display the rows...

```
int counter = 0;
for (String breads : breadInfo)
{
    System.out.println(++counter + "\t" + breads);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am really surprized how does it print `White bread 1.50` when you are adding `elems[0]+ " $" + elems[1]` in the array(notice the `$` sign in between).

Not to print `1 White bread`, do you want to truncate the `$" + elems[1]` from the end of the string before printing index in the front??

If yes: try below:

```
      int ind = 1;
      for (String breads : breadInfo){
         System.out.println(ind++ + "\t" + breads.split("\\$")[0]);
      }
```

Please note: `breads.split("$")[0]` will return `White bread` from `White bread $1.50` string stored in the array.

Comment: oh no sorry, I just forgot to add the dollar sign on my console it shows the $. my bad!

Comment: @JustinPancakeRazon Not an issue. Does this answer help? It splits your string back and prints the bread with index in front. Also looking at you code snippet, may I request you to accept the previous answer?